# How to Convert NLP Question to Knowledge Graph triple?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, information-extraction, nlp-question-answering, knowledge-graph

I have what I think is a simple question.  I am trying to put together a question answering system and I am having trouble converting a natural question to a knowledge graph triple.  Here is an example of what I mean:

Assume I have a prebuilt knowledge graph with the relationship:

((Todd) -[:picked_up_by]-> (Jane))

How can I make this conversion:

"Who picked up Todd today?" -> ((Todd) -[:picked_up_by]-> (?))

I am aware that there is a field dedicated to "Relationship Extraction", but I don't think that this fits that problem if I could name it, "question triple extraction" would be the name of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You say your knowledge graph is pre-built but then you want to extract a triplicate from a question? Did you mean to use the word "desired" instead of "pre-built" in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, it looks like a relation extraction problem, with your custom relations. Since the question is too generic, this is not an answer, just some links.

- Check out reading comprehension:  [projects on github](https://github.com/topics/reading-comprehension)  and [lecture by Christopher Manning](https://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/talks/SIGIR2016-Deep-Learning-NLI.pdf)
- Also, look up [Semantic Role Labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_role_labeling).